# NPM Permission Denied Exit Status 126

Tags: node.js, unix, npm, centos, vagrant

I am running a node process inside of vagrant and am getting a `ELIFECYCLE` (Permission denied....exit status 126) error when I run the command:

`NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js ./index.js`.

the babel-node.js file has `-rw-rw-r--`
the ./index.js file has `-rw-rw-r--`

Everything works fine locally (not on vagrant)

Also, I am using a CentOS image in my vagrant vm

Things I've tried:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064773/npm-install-how-to-run-build-scripts-with-sufficient-permissions?rq=1) post recommended doing a `chmod +x file.js` but that did not work

Comment: Is your directory mounted over NFS ?